# Is it true that $U \cap \overline{E_1 \setminus E_2} \neq \varnothing$ implies $U \cap (E_1 \setminus E_2) \neq \varnothing$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $x \in \overline{E_1 \setminus E_2}$. Is it true that if
$$U \cap \overline{E_1 \setminus E_2} \neq \varnothing$$
for every open neighborhood of $x$ then
$$U \cap (E_1 \setminus E_2) \neq \varnothing\ ?$$

Note: here $\overline E$ denotes the closure of $E$. It seems intuitively true, but I cannot come up with a proof. I need this result to prove another one, from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755161/proving-that-overline-overlinee-1-setminus-e-2-setminus-e-2-overline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Note that $x \in \overline{E_1 \setminus E_2}$ is equivalent to : for all open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$, $U \cap (E_1 \setminus E_2) \neq \emptyset$, or in fact the shape of the set does not matter:

$x \in \overline{A}$ iff for every open set $U$ that contains $x$ we have: $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

In fact for an open set $U$ the statements $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ is equivalent to $U \cap \overline{A}$, by the same reasoning.

Comment: Right. After tinkering with the definitions for a bit I found that an equivalent way to put it is to see that we can also write $x \in \overline{A} \implies x \in \overline{\overline{A}} \iff \forall U \in \mathcal U_x, U \cap \overline{A} \neq \varnothing$.